"The resulting array was too large" from Googlesheets importdata -- but it is not that big
I am currently pulling data into my Google Sheet from the following webpage: https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/leaderboard/home-runs?player_type=Batter&team=&min=0&cat=adj_xhr&year=2024
For other data on the website, I have been able to do this using importdata() and adding "&csv=1" to the end of the URL. So in this case:
=importdata("https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/leaderboard/home-runs?player_type=Batter&team=&min=0&cat=adj_xhr&year=2024&csv=1")

However, when I try that syntax for this page of the website, I get the error "The resulting array was too large"
I find this odd because the table is not large at all, less than 500 rows. Even if I change "min=0" to a higher number (making the table even smaller) the data will not load.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If you try the cell:

=importdata("https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/leaderboard/home-runs?player_type=Batter&team=&min=25&cat=adj_xhr&year=2024")

You'll notice your response is coming back in an HTML form, so the table is encoded within that link. You can either:
a. Decode the HTML and parse out what you want (difficult)
b. Find a new link which could return you just the table (may not exist)

hm, okay -- so strange the rest of the site does not function that way. There has to be a workaround haha I'm gonna keep trying.

Oh I actually see why this is different. There is no "download CSV" button like there is elsewhere on the site. What a shame.

Very weird it acts like that, glad I could help point you in the right direction, this was my first answer! Can't upvote yet because I don't have enough points...lol
